# How to display post featured image under category tab in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyone who could help me to find out, how to display all relevant featured image for each post under the category tab? I'm using the WordPress 3.9.2 and this is the website link : http://www.thebodyshop.ie/blog/whats-hot/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have theme support for post thumbnails and *within the loop*:

```
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail